# Netcat: connection lost before transfer is complete

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, netcat

Interesting thing with Netcat (nc) in CentOS 5 or 6 (nc-1.84-10.fc6 or nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64). How can I work it around? I can't find a bug about this, but

It models a file transfer to a remote host, where the file is transformed, then the result is sent back. In this example transformation is "cat".

**The server (localhost):**

```
$ mkfifo nctest.fifo
$ while :; do
      nc -l 5000 <nctest.fifo | cat >nctest.fifo
      echo -n .
      sleep 1
  done
```

**The client (localhost):**

```
$ cat testfile | nc 127.0.0.1 5000 > outfile
$ ls -l
total 9724
prw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Nov  4 14:17 nctest.fifo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4930560 Nov  4 14:17 outfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5000000 Nov  4 14:09 testfile
```

Outfile's size varies from zero to 5000000. I can add "-w2" to client, but it's no use.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... ok, I *think* I know what's going on here.  Since you're starting your server with a pipeline command (using the '|' symbol), there's a relationship between the `nc` process and the `cat` process.  When the `nc` processing sees an EOF on the TCP connection, it exits... which then causes the `cat` process to exit as well (even though it has yet to read everything from the pipe).

You cat fix this by changing your pipeline to something like so:

```
  nc -l 5000 <nctest.fifo | cat >nctest.fifo &
  wait
  echo -n .
```

...note, the '&' and `wait` calls.  Of course, this will probably leave a background job running so you'll want to add a SIGCHLD handler to your shell script to make sure you shoot it in the head when you're done (I'll leave that part as an exercise for the ready).